# Unable to send firebase fcm push notiication to android device from Java server

Tags: java, firebase, server, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Unable to send firebase fcm push notiication to android device.

When I send test message from firebase console, it goes to device. So Android side code is working fine.

For Backend Java server, I am using firebase sdk

```
public void sendNotification2(String notification, String title, String to) {
    String registrationToken = to;

    Message message = Message.builder().putData("score", "850").putData("time", "2:45")
            .setToken(registrationToken).build();

    String response;
    response = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(message);
    System.out.println("Successfully sent message: " + response);
}
```

Code outputs: *Successfully sent message: projects/myappname/messages/0:1590590793114288%9cceaf10deffd7abc*

But the device doesn't receive notification.

Answer (score 0):

It would be important to clarify if your app is in background or foreground while sending the message from backend, in fcm this is important to consider.
In this case, you send a data message, not a notification message.
The difference is explained in the doc: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

That means, you should receive this message in the overriden onMessageReceived(...)-method when the app is in the foreground and in the background. 
(You can control this with a debug log command.)

If you use data messages, you can define custom key-value pairs and implement the notification process on your own, when the app is in the foreground and background. With firebase console in contrast, you send notification messages, they are processed in the background of your app automaticly, in the foreground the overriden onMessageReceived(...) is triggered.

Here is an example of building a notification message (with different priorities which should not confuse you):

```
private Message createFCMMessageWithNormalPriority(String notificationMessage) {
    return Message.builder().setNotification(createFCMNotification(notificationMessage)).setToken(registrationToken)
            .setAndroidConfig(createAndroidConfigWithNormalMessagePriority()).build();
}

private Message createFCMMessageWithHighPriority(String notificationMessage) {
    return Message.builder().setNotification(createFCMNotification(notificationMessage)).setToken(registrationToken)
            .setAndroidConfig(createAndroidConfigWithHighMessagePriority()).build();
}

private AndroidConfig createAndroidConfigWithHighMessagePriority() {
    return createAndroidConfigWithPriority(Priority.HIGH);
}

private AndroidConfig createAndroidConfigWithNormalMessagePriority() {
    return createAndroidConfigWithPriority(Priority.NORMAL);
}

private AndroidConfig createAndroidConfigWithPriority(Priority priority) {
    return AndroidConfig.builder().setPriority(priority).build();
}

private Notification createFCMNotification(String notificationMessage) {
    return Notification.builder().setBody(notificationMessage).setTitle(NOTIFICATION_CONTENT_TITLE).build();
}
```